# using random in tar to decompress files

Tags: linux, tar, random

i want to decompress tar to specific folder, using random (
or anything else), because the content of tar is similar

In Win/batch random is used:

```
SET /A num=%random% %%100
for /d /r . %%d in (%folder%) do @if exist "%%d" ren "%%d" folder%num%
```

But in Linux/bash (???)

This is my case:

folder/1.tar 2.tar 3.tar.gz

```
cat *.tar.* *.tgz | tar -C folder/$RANDOM -zxvf - -i
```

example

```
folder/
   1/content of 1.tar
   2/content of 2.tar
   3/content of 3.tar.gz
```

Comment: You're sending a stream of multiple tar files into a single tar.  Try using a loop, like you're doing on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This achieves what you're after

```
for F in *.tar *.tgz; do R=$RANDOM ; mkdir folder/$R ; tar -C folder/$R -zxvf $F -i; done
```

Comment: While probably not a problem to risk collisions with `$RANDOM` it might be better to use `mktemp -d folder/XXXXXX` or something like that to get the temp directory